# wait for page load in success of ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, pageload

I have an ajax call like

```
$.ajax({...
```

and in the success callback there is a line of code like

```
var editor = $find("<%= NewsDetail.ClientID%>");
```

I have to tell this `$find()` to run later like in `pageLoad()` but it still must be inside the success callback.

how can I achieve that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do that. One is make the $find at document ready or
In the success make a timeout

```
 $.ajax().success(function(data){
  var editors = data;
     // I supose you print items...

     // then 
  setTimeout(function(){
     var editor = $find("<%= NewsDetail.ClientID%>");
  },600)

 })
```

Comment: How can you possibly tell that 600ms is what the OP mean with their vague and unclear question? You even wrote in a comment _"I suppose you print items..."_ and there isn't really any reason to wait 600ms after that

Answer (score 0):

It is an async control flow problem. If you use lib [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel), code would be like

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback) { $ajax({ success: callback }) },
  function(callback) { /* callback if dom ready*/ }
], function(err, results) {
  if (!err) {
    const value = results[0]
    /* do your stuff */
  }
})
```